# AVQueuePlayer stutters when modifying the next item in line

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avqueueplayer

The audio playback stutters for a brief moment when modifying the queue.

Whenever I try to modify the next item in the line of playback, the audio always stutters.
It doesn't matter if I add a new element, or remove the next in-line element.

Sample code:

```swift
let currentItem = queuePlayer.currentItem
queuePlayer.insert(someNewItem, after: currentItem)
```